# Table from MySQL not displaying on website. Query returning 0 rows

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I would be grateful for any insight relating to my issue described below. Please excuse my ignorance as I am working to lessen it.

I am using PHPMyAdmin to create the database and php to connect a website to the database.
I have confirmed that the database does connect and I can create a form on the website to populate fields in the database.

What I cannot do is create a Query that returns results and publishes them on the website. I have used YouTube videos, Code Igniter tutorials and W3 tutorials and continually end up with the same problem. Deduction leads me to believe that there are issues with my database.

This is the relevant code:

```
 <?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$dbname = "news";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$sql = "SELECT id, title, slug FROM ci_nws";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);


if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "<br> id: ".$row["id"]. " - Name: ".$row["title"]. " " .$row["slug"] . "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

The error message refers to line 18

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
```

the "0 results" does display below the error message.

I am using

**Database server**
Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
Server type: MySQL
Server connection: SSL is not being used Documentation
Server version: 5.6.46-cll-lve - MySQL Community Server (GPL)
Protocol version: 10

Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)

**Web server**
cpsrvd 11.78.0.38
Database client version: libmysql - 5.1.73
PHP extension: mysqliDocumentation curlDocumentation mbstringDocumentation
PHP version: 7.2.7

**phpMyAdmin**
Version information: 4.8.3

If relevant I am using Godaddy economy hosting package.

Any thoughts?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sure your table name is `ci_nws`? Maybe `ci_news`?

Comment: localhost is for your own computer, your credentials should be provided by your hosting service

Comment: u_mulder - good catch. It is ci_news. I will update the code supplied. This was done to test if I would receive a different error message with the incorrect table name. It had no effect.

Comment: Aprendiz 1 - Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You missed the database name from the connection

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "";     //<-- needs a valid username
$password = "";     //<-- needs a valid passsword for this username
$dbname = "news";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
//             -----------------missing part here     ^^^^^^^
```

> Remember, A MySQL instance can have multiple databases within it. So you must select the database you want to use either as part of the connection call or as a seperate [`mysqli_select_db()` call](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.select-db.php)